# Why request statuses/update_with_media api ,but response Could not authenticate with OAuth

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

I request https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.xml ,always response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<hash>
  <request>/1/statuses/update_with_media.xml</request> 
  <error>Could not authenticate with OAuth.</error> 
</hash>
```

First,get signature
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fupload.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate_with_media.xml&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3DGdeHOOii4RO9zutMSnQA%26oauth_nonce%3D5804729%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1314295310%26oauth_token%3D18774753-prAGJ6cU0tCZcFnalhLUzlwM7xGqIBlOueahLy2Cj%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3D1

Secondly，create HTTP connection

POST /1/statuses/update_with_media.xml HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: themattharris' HTTP Client
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="GdeHOOii4RO9zutMSnQA", oauth_nonce="6234982",oauth_signature="AxolJLe8rKy5SBB44HxIdWRfTpY%3d", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1314295916", oauth_token="18774753-prAGJ6cU0tCZcFnalhLUzlwM7xGqIBlOueahLy2Cj",oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=e4f86ea7-e11a-43f4-8204-f3f520ecb9a9
Host: upload.twitter.com
Content-Length: 25015
Connection: Keep-Alive

--e4f86ea7-e11a-43f4-8204-f3f520ecb9a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

1

--e4f86ea7-e11a-43f4-8204-f3f520ecb9a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media[]"; filename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

BM"

--f901ff99-f9cb-4318-a7fa-6d4bca164b4a--

Any help appreciated!